# Why is there sometimes a name on the SSL badge?

Tags: ssl, https

**Why is there a name on one of the SSL badges, but not on the other one?** Why do they look different?

[image: ssl badges]

The URL on the top uses GeoTrust, wile the bottom one only uses a RapidSSL certificate. Could that be the reason?

Out of curiosity, what is the reason behind this? Is the badge with name more secure and/or expensive?

Comment: And please feel free to edit the question if "badge" is not the correct term for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL sites with the green bar are using *Extended Validation* certificates.

[Digicerts' Extended Validation](https://www.digicert.com/ev-ssl-certification.htm?gclid=CNPMiJjag8kCFY-VfgodACwH9w)

They are more expensive and from what I understand they do a more extensive background check before they issue it.

Comment: Ok. Then why doesn't, for instance, Google use it? Google could afford it, right?

Comment: If I had to guess its because they are a household name vs other sites that are not so much and the sites that aren't a household name want to instill an additional level of trust to their users.  I don't believe all CAs have the ability to issue EVs either so that would narrow down the list of Issuers that I as the end user would need to put my trust in when using a site that is running SSL

Comment: I'm using RapidSSL as my CA. It's 14 € per year for a private site, which is fair. But I'll pass on GeoTrust and their EV because it's way too expensive. Thanks for your answer! Clears things up...

Comment: Google makes a lot of use of wildcard certificates (e.g. *.google.com) and EV certificates cannot be wildcard certs. Also some in Google don't think EV means much or should be used: they disagree with certs being used to provide validation of a website's content as they don't think that's a CA's job.